# Probability measure on $\mathcal B^1$ corresponding to discontinuous distribution

Tags: probability-theory

> **Problem.** Let $\Bbb{Q}=\{r_1,r_2, r_3,...\}$ and define $$F(x)=2\cdot \sum_{j=1}^\infty 3^{-j}\cdot \mathbf 1_{[r_j,\infty)}(x) \qquad (x\in \Bbb{R}).$$
>
> 1. Prove that $F$ is a strictly increasing distribution function.
> 2. Where is $F$ continuous and where is $F$ discontinuous?
> 3. Let $P$ be the probability measure on $\mathcal B^1$ corresponding to $F$. Find $P(\{r_j\})$ and $P(\Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Q})$.

I've already proved the first claim, and I found that $F$ is continuous at $x\in \Bbb{R}$ iff $x\notin \Bbb{Q}$.

I haven't been able to compute $P(\{r_j\})$ but once we have that, we can compute $P(\Bbb{R}\setminus \Bbb{Q})=1-\sum_{j=1}^\infty P(\{r_j\})$. We have $P(\{r_j\})=F(r_j)-P( (-\infty,r_j))$ but how do I find $P( (-\infty,r_j))$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$P( (-\infty,r_j))=\lim\limits_{x \to r_j^-} F(x)=2 \cdot \sum_{r_i <r_j} 3^{-i}$$ and $$P(\{r_j\})=2 \cdot \sum_{r_i \le r_j} 3^{-i}$$ Finally $$P(\{r_j\})=2 \cdot 3^{-j}$$